# Android frequency counter of ArrayList not working

Tags: android, arraylist

I have a frequency counter of an ArrayList that seems to function only part of 
the time.

```
List<String> winners= new ArrayList<String>();
```

Code:

```
String newWinner = "Bob, H";

int count = Collections.frequency(winners, newWinner);
    Log.e("New Winner =", newWinner);
    Log.d(TAG, "Winners = " + winners + count);
```

Which returns:

E/New Winner =: Bob, H

E/d: Winners = [, Bob, H, George, E, Bob, H] 2

This is correct. Further down the line all of a sudden this happens:

E/New Winner =: Bob, H

D/d: Winners = [, Bob, H, George, E, Bob, H] 1

How is this possible? There are no static variables etc.

Comment: are you calling it twice? how are the logs being displayed twice?

Comment: Yes. It is called twice. That is why I don't understand why the count number can be different.